# C++ reference return

Tags: c++

In this example

```
class Object {
  Object(int val);
}


std::map<unsigned, Object> myMap;
Class Foo {

    Object &getObject (unsigned Id, int val) {

    auto pair = myMap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(Id), std::forward_as_tuple(val));
    if (pair.second) {
      // do something
    }
    else {
      // do another
    }
    return pair.first->second;
  }

}
```

is the returned reference in the pair (destroyed outsize the function) stay valid ?

Comment: Please use English for this site (including the title).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it stays valid.

`emplace` returns a `std::pair` with `first` being an iterator to the inserted element and `second` being a `bool` stating if the emplace was successful.

If you're sure that `second` is `true` then the iterator in `first` is pointing to the element inside the map and thus taking a reference of that object will work.

Just make sure `myMap` outlives any `getObject()` calls of course.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the scope of myMap is global, the reference will be always valid i.e., it won't point to garbage but rather to an actual element in the standard map.